# NSIS license file based on language selection

Tags: nsis

Not quite sure how to accomplish this...  I'm using NSIS to build an installer for some apps, and the installer supports English and Japanese. How would I tell NSIS to use one license file (license.txt) if the user selected English, and a different file (license.ja-JP.txt) if they selected Japanese?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this thread: [Multilingual EULA using LicenseLangString](http://forums.winamp.com/printthread.php?s=1d19f51e5d2de8b9768d0c5f58c06def&threadid=259423) its old but still relevant.

Comment: Thanks! the thread contained the solution. Should have looked harder myself, I guess.

Comment: In case that thread goes away, the solution (for me at least) was to use `LicenseLangString` rather than `LangString` to define the appropriate filename.

Comment: Well, this page contains an error, to get it as easy as possible, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9609268/1576300

Answer (score 0):

To summarize it, try something like this.  Order is very important.

```
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "French"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Spanish"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Italian"
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Portuguese"

LicenseLangString MUILicense ${LANG_ENGLISH} "C:\EULA\EULA_EN.txt"
LicenseLangString MUILicense ${LANG_FRENCH} "C:\EULA\EULA_FR.txt"
LicenseLangString MUILicense ${LANG_SPANISH} "C:\EULA\EULA_ES.txt"
LicenseLangString MUILicense ${LANG_ITALIAN} "C:\EULA\EULA_IT.txt"
LicenseLangString MUILicense ${LANG_PORTUGUESE} "C:\EULA\EULA_PT.txt"

!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_RADIOBUTTONS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "$(MUILicense)"
```